# Error consulta oracle

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, hql

Hola tengo esta consulta pero me salta un error diciendo que falta paréntesis derecho:

```
 select to_char(trunc(fecha,'HH')+(30*round(to_char( trunc(fecha,'MI'),'MI')/30))/1440,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AS fecha, SUM(total) AS total 
        from (SELECT  FECHA_CREACION AS FECHA, Count(FECHA_CREACION) AS TOTAL
                FROM ROBOT_CONTEO_CONSULTA
                GROUP BY FECHA_CREACION)
        WHERE fecha BETWEEN TO_DATE(:fechaDesde,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE(:fechaHasta, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
        GROUP BY to_char(trunc(fecha,'HH')+(30*round(to_char( trunc(fecha,'MI'),'MI')/30))/1440,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi') 
        ORDER BY fecha ASC;
```

El error es en el rango de fechas del between, estoy pasandole por parámetros el fechaDesde y el fechaHasta, si hago por ejemplo en el where:

```
 WHERE fecha BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-20 AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Va perfecto, por lo que no entiendo que está mal, si hago esto: (que es lo que quisiera hacer)

```
WHERE fecha BETWEEN :fechaDesde AND :fechaHasta
```

Me dice que falta una palabra clave, alguna idea, lo necesito así para poderlo definir como vista.
Pdta: esta consulta me trae el total de consultas en tramos de media hora.

Comment: debes verificar que valor le estás mandando a travez de *fechaDesde* y *fechaHasta*, puede que le estés enviando valores no válidos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, estoy enviando dates con formato correcto, esto lo sé pues tengo otra consulta que recibe las mismas variables y trabaja bien, por lo que eso me deja aún más confundido